# What implies that $D[X]$ is an UFD?

Tags: field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

If $D[X]$ is an UFD, then $D$ is at least another UFD and here is my thought: if $x \in D$, I define $f(X) \in D[X]$ by $f(X) = x$. As $D[X]$ is an UFD, then there exists ${\{f_i(X)\}}_{i = 1}^n \subset D[X]$ such that
$$
x = f(X) = \prod_{i = 1}^n f_i(X)\mbox{.}
$$
As $D[X]$ is an UFD, then particularly it is an integral domain, so
$$
0 = \deg f = \sum_{i = 1}^n \deg f_i
$$
and it implies that $\deg f_i = 0$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$, so exist ${\{x_i\}}_{i = 1}^n \subset D$ such that $f_i(X) = x_i$ for all $i = 1 , \ldots , n$ and thus
$$
x = \prod_{i = 1}^n x_i
$$
and it implies automatically that $D$ is an UFD. But my question is: can I state that $D$ is a field or a PID (supposing that $D[X]$ is only an UFD)? I have wondered this question because the next statement is (as my thought) true: $R$ is a field if $R[X]$ is a PID, and is a stronger than to state: if $R[X]$ is a PID, then $R$ is another PID.

Comment: $D$ is a UFD if and only if $D[X]$ is a UFD. See [10.119.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034O) for the other part (but it's a classic result that can be found in any book).

Comment: Does the equivalence between $D$ UFD and $D[X]$ UFD implies that $D$ is not a necessarily a PID if $D[X]$ is a UFD?

Comment: Yes, of course. Otherwise e wouldn't bother having two names for the same thing.

Comment: Oh okay, I have just realized that $D$ is not necessarily a PID (and therefore neither a field) if $D[X]$ is a UFD. For example, $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is an UFD and is not a PID, so, fixing $D = \mathbb{Z}[X]$, we have that $D[X]$ is a UFD, but $D$ is not a PID. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you!